# Sum from infinity to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

How does one evaluate the following limits?

1. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty (1)$
2. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty k^{-1}$
3. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty 2^{-k}$

Do all three limits evaluate to $0$? If so, why? Perhaps only the third limit evaluates to $0$, while the first two are undefined. Again, why? @PeterTamaroff pointed out that the first two limits are undefined for fixed $n$, but does that necessarily imply they are undefined in the limit?

Comment: All three terms are already meaningless for any fixed $n$. One can study the limit of a sequence if one really has one.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff True, but does that necessarily imply they are meaningless as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Also, in light of your comment, I've edited the third limit so that it is meaningful for fixed $n$.

Comment: I repeat: if you want to talk about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n$, the $s_n$ have to be "something". In this case, at best, we can say $s_n=+\infty$. In the third case, the limit is $0$; since you're subtracting from $1$ the partial sums of $1+2^{-1}+\cdots$ that converge to it.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks, I understand now :-)

Comment: To whomever downvoted this question to -1: I've found a useful rule on StackExchange websites is to *always* explain a downvote in the comments. Some users may be more active in other communities and may not understand why a question in a particular community is considered a "bad" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sequence $$\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty 1\right)_{n \geq 1}.$$ This sequence is $$(\infty,\infty,\infty,\ldots).$$  Hence, if we wish to define a limit of this sequence, it should be $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \infty=\infty.$$

The second example is resolved in the same way (since the series is also divergent).

In the third case, the sequence is $$\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\right)_{n \geq 1}.$$  Since $$\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{2^k}=1,$$ the sequence is $$(1,\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4},\ldots)$$ so $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}=0.$$

Answer (score 3):

As limits are usually defined, you can only take $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ of an *actual sequence* of real numbers, so the first two limits are in fact meaningless, while the third evaluates to $0$ since $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \to 0$.

However, it is possible to discuss convergence in the extended real line $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\} = [-\infty, \infty]$.  In this framework, observe that the sequences of partial sums for the first two sums both approach $\infty$, so both sums are equal to $\infty$ for any fixed $n$.  Then the first and second limits are the limit of the sequence $\infty, \infty, \infty, \dots$, which converges to $\infty$.  The third limit is still $0$ as it was before.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I've given the answer tick to @Rebecca since you both provided the same answer but she posted first (by a small margin :-). Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Although your second sum

> 2) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty k^{-1}$

converges to 0, it is intresting that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{2n} k^{-1} = \ln 2$

looking for other cases that base index starts from some infinity?